# ImmutableJS: Return unchanged List after push

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

With ImmutableJS is there a way to push an "empty" value onto a List, returning the same unchanged List? For example, if I have a List `xs` and an Option `a`, I'd like to do something like:

```
xs.push(a.getOrElse(null)) // doesn't work as intended
```

equivalent to:

```
xs.concat(a.map(a => [a]).getOrElse([])) // works as intended
```

I'd like to use the cleaner syntax and O(1) efficiency of push though.

Comment: you probably meant `xs ::: Nil`, assuming `xs` is itself a list.  In scala `::`  is the List "cons" operator between a single element on the left and List on the right.

Comment: actually yeah I'm not sure what I was even thinking. I'll remove the first line because it's not relevant

Answer (score 0):

The push method in ImmutableJS takes zero or more arguments, so you should be able to use the spread operator on an empty array to get the functionality you're looking for.

```
xs.push(...a.getOrElse([]))
```

The caveat to this is that whatever result you get from getOrElse would need to be in array format.

Comment: Don't think this will work. This pushes an empty array onto my list.

Comment: Sorry, should have tested.  I've updated the answer.  You should be able to use the spread operator to fix that.